# MySQL: Waiting for metadata lock with ALGORITHM=COPY

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to execute an ALTER TABLE in MySQL. MySQL only lets me execute it with the ALGORITHM=COPY (because I need to change the type of a column).

There aren't queries using that table (to write neither to read).

But, I don't know why, when I execute the ALTER there are queries (UPDATES) which are not using this table (they are in a transaction) locked. MySQL says "mysql waiting for metadata lock".

So the question is, why the query is waiting for metadata lock if the UPDATE is not using the table altered?

I read some doc:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html#alter-table-performance
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl-performance.html#innodb-online-ddl-locking-options

But I don't understand why the queries are locked for metadata.

Reproduction of the problem in dev environment:

First, do the alter:

```sql
ALTER TABLE API.SEARCHES_ELEMENTS
  MODIFY COLUMN TYPE ENUM('A', 'B') NOT NULL,
  ALGORITHM=COPY;
```

Second, change values in other tables (there isn't transaction):

```sql
UPDATE CLIENTS
SET NAME = CONCAT('test-', RAND())
WHERE ID_CLIENT = 1;
```

The locks:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM performance_schema.metadata_locks
INNER JOIN performance_schema.threads ON THREAD_ID = OWNER_THREAD_ID
WHERE
  PROCESSLIST_ID <> CONNECTION_ID();
```

[image: metadata_locks]

Maybe the problem is due the lock over the SCHEMA?

Comment: Do you have `autocommit=ON`?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the idea is to avoid the ALGORITHM=COPY ([rebuilds without in-place mode](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html#online-ddl-column-operations))

So instead of modify the column type

```sql
ALTER TABLE API.SEARCHES_ELEMENTS
  MODIFY COLUMN TYPE ENUM('A', 'B') NOT NULL,
  ALGORITHM=COPY;
```

is better to create a new column, copy the data and remove the old one:

```sql
ALTER TABLE API.SEARCHES_ELEMENTS
  ADD COLUMN TYPE_NEW ENUM('A', 'B') NOT NULL AFTER TYPE,
  ALGORITHM=INSTANT;

LOCK TABLES API.SEARCHES_ELEMENTS WRITE;

UPDATE API.SEARCHES_ELEMENTS SET TYPE_NEW = TYPE;

ALTER TABLE API.SEARCHES_ELEMENTS
  RENAME COLUMN TYPE TO TYPE_OLD,
  RENAME COLUMN TYPE_NEW TO TYPE,
  ALGORITHM=INSTANT;

UNLOCK TABLES;

ALTER TABLE API.SEARCHES_ELEMENTS
  DROP COLUMN TYPE_OLD,
  ALGORITHM=INPLACE;
```

Note: adding a value in [ENUM](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html#online-ddl-column-syntax-notes) might be use the algorithm=instant

> Modifying the definition of an ENUM or SET column by adding new
> enumeration or set members to the end of the list of valid member
> values may be performed instantly or in place, as long as the storage
> size of the data type does not change. For example, adding a member to
> a SET column that has 8 members changes the required storage per value
> from 1 byte to 2 bytes; this requires a table copy. Adding members in
> the middle of the list causes renumbering of existing members, which
> requires a table copy.

Answer (score 0):

A tables metadata is not only locked when a running query is using it, but also if it has previously been used in an active transaction until that transaction commits or rolls back, to prevent the table from changing while still being referenced by the transaction.

If you are running at least MySQL 5.7 and have the performance_schema enabled you can check for current metadata locks via the `performance_schema.metadata_locks` table.

See also:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/performance-schema-metadata-locks-table.html

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/metadata-locking.html

Comment: thanks for the reply. There weren't transactions using the table. But the problem occurs even without transactions. I added some queries with the problem and added the metadata locks info.

Comment: your update on the CLIENTS table is explicitly waiting on a SHARED_WRITE lock on the SEARCH_ELEMENTS table.

Is there maybe a BEFORE UPDATE or AFTER UPDATE trigger on CLIENTS that tries to modify SEARCH_ELEMENTS?

Comment: no, there isn't

Comment: It's waiting on all tables in the schema

Comment: No, only the 3rd entry in the metadata_locks query output shows as "PENDING", and that is waiting for a SHARED_WRITE on table API.SHARED_ELEMENTS to be granted explicitly.